# Guice stack trace was not complete

Tags: guice

I remember the guice stack trace used to be complete starting all the way from the object I get with inject.getInstance(App.class)

For some reason, the stack trace now stops at a provider method like so

```
@Provides
public Interface buildRemoteClient() { }
```

so I have

```
at ClientXXX
at XXXModule.buildRemoteClient()
```

then it is done?  this is very odd since I override this method in my TestModule.  I don't see who is being injected with this as the chain should have been cut long before this method gets called.  Was there a change in guice 4.0 or something?

More detail

```
at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.throwCreationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:466)
                    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:155)
                    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:107)
                    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96)
                    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:73)
                    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
                    at com.company.search.generalserver.GeneralServer.initialize(GeneralServer.java:166)
```

and finally this(yes, this IS the whole thing which I find very odd)...

```
2) Could not find a suitable constructor in  com.company.finagle.thrift.ClientId. Classes must have either one (and only one) constructor annotated with @Inject or a zero-argument constructor that is not private.
                   at com.company.finagle.thrift.ClientId.class(ClientId.scala:7)
                   at com.company.search.hydrator.app.XXXXModule.buildRemoteClient(XXXXModule.java:37) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> com.google.inject.util.Modules$CombinedModule -> com.twitter.search.hydrator.app.XXXXModule)
```

ok, so I added this code and it surprisingly works now BUT never stops at this codes break point.  It never executes this code at all....

```
@Provides
@Singleton
private ClientId provideId() {
  return new ClientId("hydrator");
}
```

I shouldn't need that code since I override and it should be cutting the chain...this is very bizarre but I guess it checks every dependency even though I am in test mode and that ClientId is not needed at all.

Comment: Can you provide an example stack trace?

Comment: @MattBall I added a ton more detail but essentially that was the entire stack trace(just two lines).  I don't get why it doesn't have App.class in that stack trace at all since it is THE top constructor that causes everything to get constructed...it's so weird.

Comment: Are you now using `Stage.PRODUCTION` by any chance?

Comment: I just call createInjector(module) which under the covers looks like it uses devel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The stack trace isn't fully complete because Guice isn't actually invoking the method in question.**

At injector creation time, Guice will still validate the entirety of your graph that it can discover itself. Development mode will [affect singleton creation](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Scopes#eager-singletons) but not injector validation: You aren't allowed to refer to something that Guice will never be able to provide, or else Guice risks an even-harder-to-debug runtime exception.

It looks like Guice can detect the need for a ClientId, which doesn't (and probably shouldn't) have an `@Inject`-annotated constructor. Even if it doesn't get called, you need to provide it so Guice can declare its graph complete. That's why adding your `@Provides` method helps things along, even if it's never invoked—you could equally have it `throw new RuntimeException()`.

Though the stack trace doesn't actually reflect a real invocation, it should be complete enough for you to identify the dependency that Guice can't provide. I can only imagine that your redacted ClientXXX requests a ClientId through a parameter in an `@Inject`-annotated constructor or as an `@Inject`-annotated field, or as a parameter of `buildRemoteClient()` (which is then treated as a dependency). Do you know of anywhere that an @Inject constructor or @Provides method takes a ClientId as a parameter?

(I don't know whether Modules.override is supposed to spare you from having to provide a complete original graph, nor whether any of that behavior changed in Guice 4.0. Maybe another answerer will.)